# Undefined limit of trig function when $x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Well, I tried making $$u = \frac{\pi}{2}-x$$ and also factoring the resulting $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)$ to the $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos(-u)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin(-u)$$ form and nothing appears to make me leave this indetermination.

How should I simplify this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}\;$$

PS: without using l'Hôpital's.

Comment: Had written "sen", What I meant was "sin". "Sen" is how we write sin in Portuguese, edited.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X#Geometric_Proof

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ you can proceed as follows:
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\sin (\pi/2-x)}{\pi/2-x}=1.$$
In the last equality we used the well known trig. identity $\sin{(\pi/2-x)}=\cos x.$

Comment: Wow, nice, I didn't knew this trig. identity, this really simplifies things here.